# Copy ClickOnce configuration from a previous project

Tags: clickonce

I had been working with a project (ProjectOld) and all was OK with the ClickOnce deployments (we reach the 1.0.4.6 version); for version 2.0 we started from scratch with a new project (ProjectNew) adding third-party controls, change .NET Framework version, adding Tasks, etc. So my question is: How can we use of previous ClickOnce configuration (that is in ProjectOld) to generate a ClickOnce installation in our ProjectNew that would be just an upgrade to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the suggestion of Scott i came up with this answer:
1. Use the same certificate.
2. In the project properties page in the the publish tab in the "Options..." window, ensure that the "Description" section had the same "Publisher name", "Suite name" and "Product name".
3. The Assembly (not the project) name have to be the same as the previous version.

I already made test changing this configurations, even I already did the deployment and worked as excepted, just an update to the final users !!!

Comment: Glad to hear that I was able to help, can you mark my answer as the solution ? :)

Answer (score 0):

All ClickOnce settings are stored in the project file.  I don't know of an easy way to migrate them other than right click on your old project, click 'Edit Project File' and then copy the various ClickOnce settings out of the xml and pasting them into your new project file (that is also in edit mode).

Not super elegant but will work.  Quite sure there is no tool to do migrate for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, with that on mind what I did was to check all the options between both projects in the publish tab of the project properties. And I come up with this conclusion: 1. Use the same certificate. 2. In the publish tab in the "Options..." window, ensure that the "Description" section had the same "Publisher name", "Suite name", "Product name". 3. The Assembly name have to be the same as the previous version. With these three things I did what I wanted.